# PHP combine array

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array:

```
$ar = array(
 0 => array('id' => '1', 'pname' => 'text'),
 1 => array('id' => '2', 'pname' => 'text2'),
 2 => array('id' => '2', 'pname' => 'text3'),
 3 => array('id' => '3', 'pname' => 'text4'),
 4 => array('id' => '4', 'pname' => 'text5'),
 5 => array('id' => '4', 'pname' => 'text6'),
 6 => array('id' => '4', 'pname' => 'text7'),

);
```

I want to get array like this:

```
$result = array(
 0 => array('id' => '1', 'pname' => 'text'),
 1 => array('id' => '2', 'pname' => array('text2', 'text3')),
 3 => array('id' => '3', 'pname' => 'text4'),
 4 => array('id' => '4', 'pname' => array('text5', 'text6', 'text7'))
);
```

need help! how to iterate first array to get result like second array?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: How does your code looks now? What are the problems, you are getting with it?

Comment: Shall we code for you... Paste your try also..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple foreach loop should do the trick, eg:

```
$array_1 = array(
    array('id' => '1', 'pname' => 'text'),
    array('id' => '2', 'pname' => 'text2'),
    array('id' => '2', 'pname' => 'text3'),
    array('id' => '3', 'pname' => 'text4'),
    array('id' => '4', 'pname' => 'text5'),
    array('id' => '4', 'pname' => 'text6'),
    array('id' => '4', 'pname' => 'text7'),
);

$iterated_array = array();
foreach ($array_1 as $value) {
    $iterated_array[$value['id']]['pname'][] = $value['pname'];
}

print_r($iterated_array);
```

Comment: And to prove that it works: http://codepad.org/3265fUl6